# Feature and time steps in LSTM MNIST dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, mnist

I've been working with LSTMs for a while and I think I have grasped the main concepts. I have been trying to play with the Keras environment for a while so that I could get a better idea of how LSTM work, so I decided to train a neural network to identify the MNIST dataset.

I know that when I train a LSTM I should give a tensor as an input (number of samples, time steps, features). I reshaped the image from a 28x28 to a single vector of 784 elements (1x784) and then I make the input_shape = (60000, 1, 784). Eventually I tried to change the number of time steps and my new input_shape becomes (60000,16,49).

What I don't understand is why when I change the number of time steps the feature vector changes from 784 to 49. I think I don't really understand the concept of time steps in an LSTM. Could you please explain it better? Possibly referring to this particular case? 
Furthermore, when I increase the time steps the precision is lower, why is so? Shouldn't it be higher?
Thank you.

**edit**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import struct
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils
train_im = open('train-images-idx3-ubyte','rb')
train_la = open('train-labels-idx1-ubyte','rb')
test_im = open('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte','rb')
test_la = open('t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte','rb')

##training images and labels

magic,num_ima = struct.unpack('>II', train_im.read(8))
rows,columns = struct.unpack('>II', train_im.read(8))
img = np.fromfile(train_im,dtype=np.uint8).reshape(rows*columns, num_ima) #784*60000

magic_l, num_l = struct.unpack('>II', train_la.read(8))
lab = np.fromfile(train_la, dtype=np.int8) #1*60000

## test images and labels

magic, num_test = struct.unpack('>II', test_im.read(8))
rows,columns = struct.unpack('>II', test_im.read(8))
img_test = np.fromfile(test_im,dtype=np.uint8).reshape(rows*columns, num_test) #784x10000

magic_l, num_l = struct.unpack('>II', test_la.read(8))
lab_test = np.fromfile(test_la, dtype=np.int8) #1*10000

batch = 50
epoch=15
hidden_units = 10
classes = 1
a, b = img.T.shape[0:]

img = img.reshape(img.T.shape[0],-1,784)
img_test = img_test.reshape(img_test.T.shape[0],-1,784)
lab = np_utils.to_categorical(lab, 10)
lab_test = np_utils.to_categorical(lab_test, 10)
print(img.shape[0:])
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(40,input_shape =img.shape[1:], batch_size = batch))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'RMSprop', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(img, lab, batch_size = batch,epochs=epoch,verbose=1)


scores = model.evaluate(img_test, lab_test, batch_size=batch)
predictions = model.predict(img_test, batch_size = batch)
print('LSTM test score:', scores[0])
print('LSTM test accuracy:', scores[1])
```

**edit 2**
Thank you very much, when I do so I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 3750 input samples and 60000 target samples.
```

I know that I should reshape the output as well but I don't know what shape it should have.

Comment: Can you post the code as well?

Comment: I just added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timesteps represent states in time like frames extracted from a video. The shape of the input passed to the LSTM should be in the form (num_samples,timesteps,input_dim). If you want 16 timesteps you should reshape your data as (num_samples//timesteps, timesteps, input_dims)

```
img=img.reshape(3750,16,784)
```

So with your batch_size=50,it will pass 50*16 images at a time. 
Right now as you keep the num_samples constant, it splits your input_dims.

**edit:**
The target array will have the same shape as the num_samples i.e 3750 in your case. All the time steps will share the same label. You have to decide what you are going to do with those MNIST sequences. Your current model classifies those sequences (not digits) into 10 classes.

Comment: thank you, I have added a small edit. If you could help me a little bit more it would be very helpful.